# Stacked image created, while most of the bands became masked

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking, random-forest, stack

I am trying to do a crop-type classification, so I created a stacked image from my collection for training by RF. However, when the collection is stacked, most of the bands inside the stacked image get masked (do not know why). Now I cannot use it for training (unless I choose one band for training), while I need all the bands to be considered for training. What should I do?

```
var L820 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")
  .filterBounds(ROI20)
  .filterDate('2020-05-01', '2020-09-30')
  .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 1)
  .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'])
  .map(addNDVI)
  .map(addNDWI)
  
var stacked_img = L820.toBands()

var sample = RicS.merge(Maize)
var train_img = stacked_img.sampleRegions({
  collection: sample,
  properties: ["class"],
  scale: 30,
})

Map.addLayer(stacked_img, null, 'stacked_img')
print('Original Training', train_img)

function addNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI')
  return image.addBands(ndvi)
}

function addNDWI(image) {
  var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5']).rename('NDWI')
  return image.addBands(ndwi)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c2af68e5a3c9da69fde63c7ce8c5ab06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all images in your image collection cover all your region. For instance, the last image:

```
Map.addLayer(L820.reduce(ee.Reducer.last()))
```

When you execute `toBands()`, each band in each image will be part of the stack, so you get a lot of masked pixels. Different areas will have different sets of pixels masked. Your classifier would be very confused.

Instead of `toBands()`, you can for instance create a median composite from the collection and classify that.

```
var composite = L820.median()
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/12e82b8613f994842cb51c4a81f8f7a1

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your answer. However, I do not think the median function will work well with my case as I am doing a crop classification which as far as I understand depends on the in-season temporal variation occurring with the bands (for example, NDVI and NDWI). So do you think of any other solution I can use?!

Comment: You can take different percentiles of your collection, create seasonal composites (using median), do some kind of time-series processing of the collection - maybe fit a 3rd order harmonic.