# Get rid of those masked tiles to continue with data processing

Tags: google-earth-engine, tiles, sentinel-2, landsat-8

I have masked tiles in my Landsat images for my area of interest, so I merged a sentinel 2 image to fill the gaps. However, after merging and continuing with the classification, those tiles are still masked so the classification does not go rightly?! How can I get rid of those masked tiles to continue with data processing?

Here is the code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/d56ec9ef5e7c2794654cf965da10b6d7?noload=1

```
// Define a function that scales and masks Landsat 8 surface reflectance images.
function prepSrL8(image) {
  // Develop masks for unwanted pixels (fill, cloud, cloud shadow).
  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

  // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
  var getFactorImg = function(factorNames) {
    var factorList = image.toDictionary().select(factorNames).values();
    return ee.Image.constant(factorList);
  };
  var scaleImg = getFactorImg([
    'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_MULT_BAND_ST_B10']);
  var offsetImg = getFactorImg([
    'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_ADD_BAND_ST_B10']);
  var scaled = image.select('SR_B.|ST_B10').multiply(scaleImg).add(offsetImg);

  // Replace original bands with scaled bands and apply masks.
  return image.addBands(scaled, null, true)
    .updateMask(qaMask).updateMask(saturationMask);
}


// Make a cloud-free Landsat 8 surface reflectance composite.
var dates = [
  ee.DateRange('2020-05-01', '2020-05-15'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-05-16', '2020-05-31'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-06-01', '2020-06-15'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-06-16', '2020-06-30'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-07-01', '2020-07-15'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-07-16', '2020-07-31'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-08-01', '2020-08-15'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-08-16', '2020-08-31'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-09-01', '2020-09-15'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-09-16', '2020-09-30')
]
//var bands = ['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5',
            // 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7']
             
var addNDVI = function(img) {
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B4', 'SR_B5']).rename('NDVI')
  return img.addBands(ndvi)
}

var addNDWI = function(img) {
  var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B5']).rename('NDWI')
  return img.addBands(ndwi)
}
var list_l8 = dates.map(function(range) {
  return ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
      .filterDate(ee.DateRange(range))
      .filterBounds(ROI)
      .map(addNDVI)
      .map(addNDWI)
      .select(['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7','NDVI', 'NDWI'])
      .mean()
      .rename(['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5','SR_B6', 'SR_B7','NDVI', 'NDWI'])
      ee.Filter.notNull
});

print(list_l8)




////import S2 stacked layer//
// cloud function to remove clouds
 function maskS2clouds(image){
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var dates = [
  ee.DateRange('2020-05-01', '2020-05-15'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-05-16', '2020-05-31'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-06-01', '2020-06-15'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-06-16', '2020-06-30'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-07-01', '2020-07-15'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-07-16', '2020-07-31'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-08-01', '2020-08-15'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-08-16', '2020-08-31'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-09-01', '2020-09-15'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-09-16', '2020-09-30')
]

var addNDVI = function(img) {
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI')
  return img.addBands(ndvi)
}

var addNDWI = function(img) {
  var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI')
  return img.addBands(ndwi)
}

var list_s2 = dates.map(function(range) {
  return ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
      .filterDate(ee.DateRange(range))
      .filterBounds(ROI)
      .map(addNDVI)
      .map(addNDWI)
      .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
      .map(maskS2clouds)
      .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI'])
      .mean()
      .rename(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI'])
})

print(list_s2)

////create a stacked layer///
var stacked_1 = ee.ImageCollection(list_l8)//.toBands().clip(ROI);
var stacked_2 = ee.ImageCollection(list_s2)//.toBands().clip(ROI);

/////Now need to combine the two stacked layer together////
  
// Since Landsat 8 and Sentinel 2 have different band designations,
// let's create a function to rename s7 bands to match up L8.
function rename(image){
  return image.select(
    ['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5','SR_B6', 'SR_B7','NDVI', 'NDWI'],
    ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI']);
    }

// Apply the rename function
var L8_rename = stacked_1.map(rename);

print('L8 stacked rename',L8_rename);

// Merge Landsat collections
var l8_s2 = L8_rename.merge(stacked_2
          .select('B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI'));
          
print('Merged collections',l8_s2);

var stacked_compo= ee.ImageCollection(l8_s2).toBands().clip(ROI);


 Map.addLayer(stacked_compo, {}, 'Stacked', false)



//////////////////training data/////////////////


//Generate 5000 random pt sample
var random1 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: rice,
  points: 1000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
})
var random2 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: maize,
  points: 1000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
})

var random3 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: cotton,
  points: 1000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
})

var random4 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: potato,
  points: 1000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
})

// Paint the reference data into an image so we can sample it.
var referenceData = ee.Image().byte().paint(rice, 0).paint(maize, 1).paint(cotton,2).paint(potato,3).rename("class")
//var merged_sample= random1.merge(random2,random3,random4);
// Place the collections in a new collection.
var combined = ee.FeatureCollection([random1, random2,random3,random4]);

// Flatten the collection to create a new collection with all the features.
var flattened = combined.flatten();



// // // // Get the values for all pixels in each polygon in the training.
var training = stacked_compo.addBands(referenceData).reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  // Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
  collection: merged_sample,
  // Set the scale to get Landsat pixels in the polygons.
scale: 30,
  //crs: 'EPSG:32636',
  tileScale: 2
});

// // Filter out the null property values and try again.
var trainingNoNulls = training.filter(
  ee.Filter.notNull(stacked_compo.bandNames().add("class"))
)
var sample=trainingNoNulls.randomColumn();//
var split=0.7
var training_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random',split));
var validation_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',split));


var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(128)
  .train({
    features: training_sample,
    //.randomColumn().filter("random < 0.7"),
    classProperty: 'class',
    inputProperties: stacked_compo.bandNames(),
    
  })

var classified = stacked_compo.classify(classifier, 'Classified')
Map.addLayer(classified,{
    min: 0,
    max: 3,
    palette: ['yellow', 'green','orange','brown']
  },
  'classification', true)

// Get a confusion matrix representing resubstitution accuracy.
var trainAccuracy = classifier.confusionMatrix();
print('Resubstitution error matrix: ', trainAccuracy);
print('Training overall accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Training kappa accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.kappa());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `ee.ImageCollection(l8_s2).toBands()`. This is probably not what you want to do. You will end up with masked bands, which the classifier doesn't like. See [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/446451/154371) answer.

I've answered your [other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/447976/154371) too, explaining the cause of your missing Landsat pixels.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel for your explanation. I changed the date range and It worked for part of the image, however, another part is still masked. Can I use the unmask() function to get rid of the remaining masked values?